# C# double to char[20]

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I would like to convert a double value to a char[20].
Ma double value is : 52715.871

Here is my code :

```
double value = init_value();
char tab[] = new char[20];
tab    =   value .ToString().ToCharArray();
```

My problem is that my tab resul is 9 size instead of a 20 size. I would like always a 20 size.

How doing this please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Comment: Look into the [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) and [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx) methods.

Comment: The type of solution you are looking for is called "padding."  You can pad with zeros or with spaces on either the left or the right to fill out the array to 20 slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tab = value .ToString().PadLeft(20, '0').ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ok with .PadLeft() :)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to fill it out with, for example:

```
var tab = value.ToString().PadLeft(20,' ').ToCharArray();
```

will give you a char array with spaces padded to the left...